# How to start (for first time) playing cricket for another country's team?

Tags: cricket, icc, cricket-world-cup

Is it possible to start(for the first time) playing cricket for another country?
if so, then does the U.S Passport work for Australia?

Comment: What do you mean, "for the first time"? No country is going to take a completely new player as an international, especially one that isn't even theirs.

Comment: I mean like if it was your first National team.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be considered eligible to play for a given country the International Cricket Council (ICC) requires the player to meet at least one of the following criteria for nationality:

> 2.1.1 the Player was born in the country whose domestic cricket governing body is the National
>   Cricket Federation;
>
> 2.1.2 at the date of submission of the relevant information to the ICC, the Player is able to
>   demonstrate (by his/her possession of a valid passport issued by the relevant country) that
>   he/she is a national of the country whose domestic cricket governing body is the National
>   Cricket Federation; or
>
> 2.1.3 at the date of submission of the relevant information to the ICC, the Player is a Resident
>   of the country whose domestic cricket governing body is the National Cricket Federation.
>   For the purposes of this Article, a Player will be deemed to be a ‘Resident' of a particular
>   country if the Player has had his/her primary and permanent home in the relevant country
>   for the immediately preceding three years, and Residence and Residency shall be
>   construed accordingly.

So for your hypothetical American passport holder assuming they weren't born in Australia the most likely way they could achieve eligibility would be to a resident of a country whose cricket was governed by Cricket Australia for 3 years preceeding selection.